# Error in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

I am trying to plot the clusters by using `ggplot2`, but i get the following error

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class factor

My data is

```
samp2

structure(list(PVALUE1 = c(0.000244, 0.000244, 0.001221, 0.000244, 
0.000732, 0.000244), PVALUE2 = c(0.000244, 0.000732, 0.000732, 
0.000732, 0.001953, 0.000244), PVALUE3 = c(0.000244, 0.001953, 
0.001221, 0.000244, 0.000244, 0.000244), PVALUE4 = c(0.000732, 
0.000244, 0.000732, 0.000732, 0.001221, 0.000244), PVALUE5 = c(0.000244, 
0.000244, 0.001221, 0.000732, 0.005859, 0.000244), PVALUE6 = c(0.000244, 
0.00293, 0.001221, 0.303711, 0.00293, 0.000244), PVALUE7 = c(0.000244, 
0.00293, 0.000244, 0.000732, 0.000732, 0.000244), PVALUE8 = c(0.000244, 
0.001221, 0.000732, 0.000244, 0.001953, 0.000244), PVALUE9 = c(0.000244, 
0.000732, 0.000732, 0.000732, 0.00293, 0.000244), PVALUE10 = c(0.000732, 
0.01416, 0.000732, 0.001953, 0.001221, 0.000244), PVALUE11 = c(0.000244, 
0.000732, 0.000732, 0.005859, 0.001953, 0.000244), cluster = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("PVALUE1", 
"PVALUE2", "PVALUE3", "PVALUE4", "PVALUE5", "PVALUE6", "PVALUE7", 
"PVALUE8", "PVALUE9", "PVALUE10", "PVALUE11", "cluster"), row.names = c("A2M", 
"AAAS", "AACS", "AADAT", "AAGAB", "AAK1"), class = "data.frame")
```

and the centres are

```
centers

PVALUE1    PVALUE2    PVALUE3   PVALUE4    PVALUE5    PVALUE6    PVALUE7    PVALUE8
1 0.49755105 0.56381653 0.56706751 0.5336074 0.54674859 0.54398645 0.56531453 0.58162957
2 0.03481979 0.04874772 0.05312517 0.0447989 0.04720369 0.05724064 0.05257442 0.06362684
     PVALUE9   PVALUE10   PVALUE11
1 0.56174089 0.59716210 0.53878320
2 0.04778373 0.06540369 0.04371612
```

The code I used is

```
ggplot(data=head(samp2$cluster), aes(x=principal_comp1, y=principal_comp2, color=cluster )) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_point(data=centers, aes(x=V1,y=V2, color='Center')) +
  geom_point(data=centers, aes(x=V1,y=V2, color='Center'), size=52, alpha=.2)
```

How to make it work.

Comment: ggplot2 accept data input as data.frane so you need to convert your list into dataframe

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your data in `ggplot` are just one column rather than the entire data.frame. Then you are calling columns that don't exist. This should fix the first part of the plot.

```
ggplot(data=samp2, aes(x=PVALUE1, y=PVALUE2, color=cluster )) + 
  geom_point()
```

TO add the centres you will need to use the names of the columns in the data.frame. Setting colour = "centre" will give you the same colour for all centres. Add the cluster number to the data.frame as a factor and use that

Comment: Can't I plot all the columns at once.

Comment: How? A 9D scatterplot? Why? Your PCA should extract the most important axes of variation in the data in the first few axes: these are the ones you want to plot. PCA9 is rarely interesting.